# PHP Recursive regex filter iterator iterator

Tags: php

I'm simply trying to loop through all the files in a directory, recursively, filtering to only those that match a pattern.

Turns out [RegexIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.regexiterator.php) gives you the regex match object, but I want the `SplInfo` object.

So here's what I've got:

```
class RegexFilterIterator extends RecursiveFilterIterator {

    private $pattern;

    public function __construct(RecursiveIterator $iterator, $pattern) {
        parent::__construct($iterator);
        $this->pattern = $pattern;
    }


    public function accept() {
        return preg_match($this->pattern, $this->current()->getFilename()) > 0;
    }
}

$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($argv[1]);
$regex = new RegexFilterIterator($dir, '/\.php5?\z/i');
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($regex);



foreach($it as $foo) {
   echo $foo->getPathname().PHP_EOL;
}
```

But this doesn't appear to be recursive.

I believe that's because `\RegexFilterIterator::accept` is actually being fed the directories too and I'm rejecting them because they don't end with `.php`.

Easy fix, right? Just amend it slightly:

```
public function accept() {
    return $this->current()->isDir() || preg_match($this->pattern, $this->current()->getFilename()) > 0;
}
```

And now it's crashing:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function RegexFilterIterator::__construct(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected in *bleep*

Which doesn't make any sense to me. Why is trying to construct more instances of `RegexFilterIterator` on its own, and how is it messing it up??

I'd put the `RegexFilterIterator` *after* the `RecursiveIteratorIterator`, but then it yells at me:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to RegexFilterIterator::__construct() must implement interface RecursiveIterator, instance of RecursiveIteratorIterator given

So... I don't know how you're supposed to use these classes.

How can I recurse all the files in a dir, and filter them with a simple regex, giving me back a generator/iterable that produces SplInfo objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found [this](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php#114504) buried in the comments on php.net, posted by "sun", and improved it a bit:

```
$directory = new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($argv[1], \FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$filter = new \RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator($directory, function ($current, $key, $iterator) {
    return $current->isDir() || preg_match('/\.php5?\z/',$current->getPathname()) > 0;
});
$iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator($filter);

foreach($iterator as $file) {
   echo $file->getPathname().PHP_EOL;
}
```

The `RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator` seems to be a bit easier to work with, rather than extending `RecursiveFilterIterator`. There's also a `FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS` flag which is handy.

Answer (score 0):

I realized we can just use a generator function to clean up that non-sense instead of mucking about with iterator interfaces:

```
function readDirRecursive($dir, $pattern=null) {
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, \FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS));
    foreach($iterator as $it) {
        if($it->isFile() && ($pattern===null || preg_match($pattern, $it->getPathname()))) {
            yield $it;
        }
    }
}


$iterator = readDirRecursive($argv[1],'/\.php5?\z/');

foreach($iterator as $file) {
   echo $file->getPathname().PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Kind of defeats what you were originally trying to do. You don't really need a generator, a single foreach would work :/

Comment: @LawrenceCherone How so? Oh..you mean I can put the `if` directly inside my foreach? Yeah... I guess so, unless I wanted to do this a whole bunch. Anyway I did figure out how to use those stupid classes, will post in a sec.